# Find documents 7 days apart in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose, we have this type of documents :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4c02c58de500fe1be1000305"),
"date" : ""20090530"
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("4c02c58de500fe1be1000005"),
"date" : ""20090607"
}
```

Is it possible to find/group all documents with 7 days between them?
With aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this, I believe you won't be needing aggregation here, if you are doing this for the same collection:

```
db.collectionName.find({date: { $gte: "20090530", $lte: "20090607" } } );
```

Reference: [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) and [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/)